# Atualizando o Gradle para 6.x

Tags: java, gradle

Estou atualizando a versão do gradle da minha aplicação, ele estava com a versão 2.3 e estou indo para a 6.7.1 e não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema:

> Could not set unknown property 'testClassesDir' for task ':systemtestRun' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.

build.gradle:

```
task systemtestRun(type: Test) {
description 'run tests'
testClassesDir = sourceSets.systemtest.output.classesDirs
classpath = sourceSets.systemtest.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath }
```

Alguem poderia me dar uma mão?

Answer (score 0):

Tente definir o diretório como abaixo antes de usá-lo na task.

```
    sourceSets {
        systemtest {
            java.srcDir file('src/seu_dire/java')
            resources.srcDir file('src/seu_diretorio_resources/resources')
        }
    }

    configurations {
        systemtestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    }

    task systemtestRun(type: Test) {
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.systemtest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.systemtest.runtimeClasspath
    }
```

Eu busquei adaptar um caso que tenho ao seu exemplo.